# So i have this code that i am using arrays of [60] and how if i add an object can i edit it afterwards in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, edit

In my program, after I add a book I can see it when I press the (4) command in the menu.

How will I be able to edit it using the (2) command in the menu?

```
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

public class library {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {    
        Management manager = new Management();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("\n\t\t^*^*^*^*^*^*^* LIBRARY  MANAGEMENT ^*^*^*^*^*^*^");

        while(true){
            System.out.println("------------------MENU----------" +
                    "---------------------");
            System.out.print("\nENTER UR CHOICE\n\t1:Add a new Book\n\t2:Edit Book Infos\n\t3:Search a Book (with ISBN)\n\t4:Show all the Books\n\t5:Delete a Book (with ISBN)\n\t6:Exit \n   :");
            int selection;
            selection=input.nextInt();
            if (selection == 1)
            {
                Book book = new Book();
                System.out.println("Adding a new book ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("name of book:");
                book.name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Author:");
                book.author = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("ISBN:");
                book.isbn = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Number of copies:");
                book.number = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("");
                manager.AddBook(book);

            }
            else
            $$$$$$$$        **if (selection == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Editing a Book ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();**$$$$$$$$$$
            }
            else
            if (selection == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Searching a  Book ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();
            }
            else
            if (selection == 4)
            {
                System.out.println("You Choose to  view all       the Books  ");
                manager.PrintAllBooks();
            }
            else
            if (selection == 5)
            {
                System.out.println("You Choose to Delete a Book ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();
            }
            else
            if(selection == 6)
            {
                System.out.println("Library System Terminated!!! ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong Choice");
            }

        }
    }
```

Here's the `Book` class:

```
public class Book {
    public String isbn;
    public String name;
    public String author;
    public int number;
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    String bookinfo = name + "    ," + author + "    ," + isbn;
}
```

Here's the `Management` class:

```
public class Management  {
    private  Book[] books =new Book [60];
    int current = 0;
    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        books[current]=book;
        current++;
    }
    public void PrintAllBooks()
    {
        for (int i=0;i&lt;current;i++)
        {
            Book b = books[i];
            System.out.println(b.name);
        }
    }
    public void Editbooks()
    {
        for (int i=0;i&lt;current;i++)
        {
            Book b = books[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Just edit the book.

Comment: `book[#] = newBook;` just simply overwrite it. This could have been easily answered by googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to know the array index of the book you want to edit. Or some how you will have to have the reference to book object that you want to edit.

Once you have  the index that you want to edit. You can do something like this.

**Replace this by**

```
$$$$$$$$        **if (selection == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Editing a Book ");
                String empty = input.nextLine();**$$$$$$$$$$
            }
```

**This**

```
if (selection == 2) {
            System.out.println("Editing a Book ");
            System.out.println("Please enter title of book to edit:");
            String title = input.next();

            Book editingBook = findBookByTitle(title);
            if(editingBook == null) {
                System.out.println("Sorry no book found with title name = " + title);
            } else {
                // Now ask user for new price etc what ever you want to edit.
                System.out.println("Please enter new price:");
                int newPrice = input.nextInt();
                editingBook.setPrice(newPrice);
                // etc. other editing to book.
            }
        }
```

In Addition you will have to add a method in your manager class. called findBookByTitle

```
/**
     * This function takes a book title and search in the book array.
     * 
     * @param title
     * @return returns null if title is not found.
     */
    public Book findBookByTitle(String title) {
        Book searchBook = null;
        for (Book book : books) {
            if(book.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
                searchBook = book;
                break;
            }
        }
        return searchBook;
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I inserted your help in my program but when i run it after i add a few books i insert the (2) command and it skips the input and tells me right away that Sorry no book found with title name

I suspect it has something to do with the null in management class

Comment: I did not run your program. I just did this to explain the approach. Please add required exception handing and other tweaks as required by your program. But if you are stuck than sure I can provide further help.

Comment: I will suggest that you debug your code in debugger. Step through it to find whats going on. If you try to find book that you have not added  then sure you will get that message.

Comment: all that was needed was  String title = input.nextLine(); to be changed to  String title = input.next();

Comment: Good!. Now if this helped you will you please accept is an answer?

Comment: Well it fixed the problem with the immediate Sorry no book found with title name but now no matter what input i put (even if that book exists with that name ) it still gives me this answer : Sorry no book found with title name. Could you point me to where that problem is?

Comment: Did you try to debug line by line?